# How to fix RestShap timeout issue after increasing to 300000

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, restsharp

I am consuming a third part api which works fine on postman but in my code, I am get timeout even after I have increase to 300000. I might be doing something wrong.

```
 var client = new RestClient("http://url/api/remote/bal");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(appSettings.Username, appSettings.Password);
            client.Timeout = 300000;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddJsonBody(new
            {
                Account = Balance.Account
            });

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            IRestResponse<TajBalanceInquiryResponse> res = client.Execute<TajBalanceInquiryResponse>(request);
```

The response error

```
"StatusCode: GatewayTimeout, Content-Type: text/html, Content-Length: 1725)"
```

Comment: Best way is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the 1st request of Postman and c#.  Then make headers in c# look like Postman.  The default headers in c# are different from Postman.  Timeout could be a failure so check the response status and see if you are getting a 200 OK or a failure which is usually a 400/500 error.

Comment: In fact, I am using the same code copied from Postman. Just made some changes. timeout in postman is -1

Comment: It doesn't matter.  The postman library and c# library are different and default values are different.

Comment: I have been able to fix it. your suggestion helped me. I was my proxy server that was blocking it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.Net C# RESTSharp 10 Minute Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54350909/net-c-sharp-restsharp-10-minute-timeout)

Comment: You didn't supply enough info to suggest proxy issue.  Usually the Postman is using the same proxy so when Postman was working, proxy issues are not my first suggestion.